# Algorithm for finding a combination of integers greater than a specified value

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I've been trying to develop an algorithm that would take an input array and return an array such that the integers contained within are the combination of integers with the smallest sum greater than a specified value (limited to a combination of size *k*).

For instance, if I have the array [1,4,5,10,17,34] and I specified a minimum sum of 31, the function would return [1,4,10,17]. Or, if I wanted it limited to a max array size of 2, it would just return [34].

Is there an *efficient* way to do this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you want to limit the array size to 5 and sum of 37 what if the list were `[1,4,5,10,17,37]`, would you want it return `[37]` or `[1,4,5,10,17]`?

Comment: This looks like a variation on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: @mbratch: It would return 37.

Comment: @AlexanderHanysz: But in this case weight is always equal to value... Shouldn't this simplify it quite a bit?

Comment: [Subset sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) is reducible to this problem.

Comment: In your example, wouldn't `k=3` return `[5,10,17]`?

Comment: @groovy It definitely would! Oops!

Comment: @crough I'm getting `[]` when I input `MinimumSum=90, MaxArraySize=4, InputData=sorted([1,4,5,31,32,34])` using thefourtheye's code. What should the result be? (my own code outputs 97)

Comment: @crough Try this one, too. `MinimumSum=90000000, MaxArraySize=4, InputData=sorted([1,4,5,31000000,32000000,34000000])` It takes about 17 seconds on my old IBM Thinkpad using PyPy, a fast python compiler. What if we added another zero? (Output with my code is instantaneous) That's my competitive spirit :)

Comment: @crough and here's another one (I didn't wait around to see how long it would take; my code's output was again instantaneous): `import random; MinimumSum = 31; MaxArraySize = 4; m = [random.randint(1,100000000) for r in xrange(1000)]; InputData = sorted(set(m))`

Comment: @crough groovy's solution is far far better than mine. Please accept his solution as accepted, so that I can delete mine.

Comment: @thefourtheye Hmm...that was not my intention...I'm not as familiar with the DP idea you proposed and have not looked it over as carefully as I could. I just noticed some special cases that could be tested. I'm not sure, however, which approach is the most efficient, generally speaking.

Comment: @thefourtheye I haven't been on SO in a while so I didn't see it! groovy's marked as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? It returns the value, but could easily be adapted to return the sequence.

Algorithm: assuming sorted input, test the k-length combinations for the smallest sum greater than min, stop after the first array element greater than min.

JavaScript:

```
var roses = [1,4,5,10,17,34]

function f(index,current,k,best,min,K)
{ 
    if (roses.length == index)
        return best
    for (var i = index; i < roses.length; i++) 
    {
        var candidate = current + roses[i]
        if (candidate == min + 1)
            return candidate
        if (candidate > min)
            best = best < 0 ? candidate : Math.min(best,candidate)
        if (roses[i] > min)
            break
        if (k + 1 < K)
        {
            var nextCandidate = f(i + 1,candidate,k + 1,best,min,K)
            if (nextCandidate > min)
                best = best < 0 ? nextCandidate : Math.min(best,nextCandidate)
            if (best == min + 1)
                return best
        }
    }
    return best
}
```

Output:

```
console.log(f(0,0,0,-1,31,3))
32

console.log(f(0,0,0,-1,31,2))
34
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a hybrid solution, with Dynamic Programming and Back Tracking. We can use Back Tracking alone to solve this problem, but then we have to do exhaustive searching (2^N) to find the solution. The DP part optimizes the search space in Back Tracking.

```
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict
MinimumSum   = 31
MaxArraySize = 4
InputData    = sorted([1,4,5,10,17,34])
# Input part is over    

Target       = MinimumSum + 1
Previous, Current = OrderedDict({0:0}), OrderedDict({0:0})
for Number in InputData:
    for CurrentNumber, Count in Previous.items():
        if Number + CurrentNumber in Current:
            Current[Number + CurrentNumber] = min(Current[Number + CurrentNumber], Count + 1)
        else:
            Current[Number + CurrentNumber] = Count + 1
    Previous = Current.copy()

FoundSolution = False
for Number, Count in Previous.items():
    if (Number >= Target and Count < MaxArraySize):
        MaxArraySize  = Count
        Target        = Number
        FoundSolution = True
        break

if not FoundSolution:
    print "Not possible"
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    print Target, MaxArraySize

FoundSolution = False
Solution      = []

def Backtrack(CurrentIndex, Sum, MaxArraySizeUsed):
    global FoundSolution
    if (MaxArraySizeUsed <= MaxArraySize and Sum == Target):
        FoundSolution = True
        return
    if (CurrentIndex == len(InputData) or MaxArraySizeUsed > MaxArraySize or Sum > Target):
        return
    for i in range(CurrentIndex, len(InputData)):
        Backtrack(i + 1, Sum, MaxArraySizeUsed)
        if (FoundSolution): return
        Backtrack(i + 1, Sum + InputData[i], MaxArraySizeUsed + 1)
        if (FoundSolution):
            Solution.append(InputData[i])
            return

Backtrack(0, 0, 0)
print sorted(Solution)
```

**Note:** As per the examples given by you in the question, Minimum sum and Maximum Array Size are strictly greater and lesser than the values specified, respectively.

For this input

```
MinimumSum   = 31
MaxArraySize = 4
InputData    = sorted([1,4,5,10,17,34])
```

Output is

```
[5, 10, 17]
```

where as, for this input

```
MinimumSum   = 31
MaxArraySize = 3
InputData    = sorted([1,4,5,10,17,34])
```

Output is

```
[34]
```

**Explanation**

```
Target       = MinimumSum + 1
Previous, Current = OrderedDict({0:0}), OrderedDict({0:0})
for Number in InputData:
    for CurrentNumber, Count in Previous.items():
        if Number + CurrentNumber in Current:
            Current[Number + CurrentNumber] = min(Current[Number + CurrentNumber], Count + 1)
        else:
            Current[Number + CurrentNumber] = Count + 1
    Previous = Current.copy()
```

This part of the program finds the minimum number of numbers from the input data, required to make the sum of numbers from 1 to the maximum possible number (which is the sum of all the input data). Its a dynamic programming solution, for knapsack problem. You can read about that in the internet.

```
FoundSolution = False
for Number, Count in Previous.items():
    if (Number >= Target and Count < MaxArraySize):
        MaxArraySize  = Count
        Target        = Number
        FoundSolution = True
        break

if not FoundSolution:
    print "Not possible"
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    print Target, MaxArraySize
```

This part of the program, finds the `Target` value which matches the `MaxArraySize` criteria.

```
def Backtrack(CurrentIndex, Sum, MaxArraySizeUsed):
    global FoundSolution
    if (MaxArraySizeUsed <= MaxArraySize and Sum == Target):
        FoundSolution = True
        return
    if (CurrentIndex == len(InputData) or MaxArraySizeUsed > MaxArraySize or Sum > Target):
        return
    for i in range(CurrentIndex, len(InputData)):
        Backtrack(i + 1, Sum, MaxArraySizeUsed)
        if (FoundSolution): return
        Backtrack(i + 1, Sum + InputData[i], MaxArraySizeUsed + 1)
        if (FoundSolution):
            Solution.append(InputData[i])
            return

Backtrack(0, 0, 0)
```

Now that we know that the solution exists, we want to recreate the solution. We use backtracking technique here. You can easily find lot of good tutorials about this also in the internet.

Comment: I'm getting `[]` when I input `MinimumSum=90, MaxArraySize=4, InputData=sorted([1,4,5,31,32,34])`. What do you think the result should be? (My own code outputs 97)

Comment: Cool. Try this one: `MinimumSum=90000000, MaxArraySize=4, InputData=sorted([1,4,5,31000000,32000000,34000000])` It takes about 17 seconds on my old IBM Thinkpad using PyPy, a fast python compiler. What if we added another zero? (Output with my code is instantaneous)

Comment: @groovy Okay. Updated the solution. I hope you understand why DP is needed here and not just backtracking. And thanks :) As you keep on pushing, I try to improvise the program.

Comment: You're welcome and thank you, too; try this one (I didn't wait around to see how long it would take; my code's output was again instantaneous): `import random; MinimumSum = 31; MaxArraySize = 4; m = [random.randint(1,100000000) for r in xrange(1000)]; InputData = sorted(set(m))`

Comment: @groovy I tried to delete this answer but SO wouldnt allow me to do so.